# Starting with blogger or WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Hy guys!

I want to start my blog about Squirrel Programming Language. Its about game server scripting. I want to create a simple website for it, shall i start it with blogger or WordPress, I know blogger hosting is free. but if i start with WordPress have i to buy web hosting for it right?
I also can use 000webhost and other free web hosting services but they really have lag and bad security. Please tell me the advantages of blogger and WordPress i want to know which one is best for me!

If i start it with blogger then in future can i change my website from blogger to WordPress?
And please suggest me a cheap and best domain provider please!

Please suggest the best. Waiting for your answers!

Thank you!

Comment: A quick google would provide you with the answers you are looking for!

Comment: I Google it but they are taking me from one page to another i i could not find correct answer, the answer is 1 line can you tell me. instead of this Google search suggestion??

Comment: If you want to "talk" about programming, go with Wordpress, and invest a little in a hosting, don't go the free host route. Why Wordpress? Because there are a lot of plugins to post code, and I assume that's important for a blog about programming.

Comment: Bro, In future can i change blogger website into wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to migrate from blogger to wordpress. However, the structure of your permalink URLs will change.

Yes, blogger itself is free, and allows you to use your own purchased domain. If you just use a subdomain of blogger.com, then of course that makes your blog even less portable should you choose to go with wordpress later.

The biggest advantages of wordpress (or drupal, or any self-hosted solution for that matter) are portability and control.

Cheap registrars and webhosts are a dime a dozen. Some are better than others. Shop around.